# CryptDB - cannot connect to proxy (ERROR 1105 (HY000): (proxy) all backends are down)

Tags: mysql, proxy, lua

I install CryptDB in Ubuntu 14.04. I want to start the proxy:

```
$ /home/user/cryptdb/bins/proxy-bin/bin/mysql-proxy \
    --plugins=proxy \
    --event-threads=4 \
    --max-open-files=1024 \
    --proxy-lua-script=$EDBDIR/mysqlproxy/wrapper.lua \
    --proxy-address=127.0.0.1:3307 \
    --proxy-backend-addresses=localhost:3306
```

and it started:

```
2015-10-26 00:04:34: [global] (*) mysql-proxy 0.9.0 started
```

Then I login mysql use this command:

```
$ mysql -u root -pletmein -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307
```

It display:

> ERROR 1105 (HY000): (proxy) all backends are down

proxy output:

> 2015-10-26 00:04:40: [global] (critical) proxy-plugin.c.1772: Cannot connect, all backends are down.

I install MySQL and CryptDB on the same VM.

I am following the steps on [CryptDB readme](https://github.com/CryptDB/cryptdb#-a-few-ways-to-run-cryptdb) on GitHub.

---

Edit: the problem below is fixed, the above problem not fix yet.

Also, the original script (`cryptdb/mysqlproxy/wrapper.lua`) cause an error:

> 2015-10-26 00:24:33: [global] (critical) (lua-error) [/home/user/cryptdb/mysqlproxy/wrapper.lua]
>
> [string "/home/user/cryptdb/mysqlproxy/wrapper.lua"]:1: attempt to concatenate a nil value

Seems the `os.getenv("EDBDIR")` return `nil` even I have set the `EDBDIR` in `~/.bashrc`: `EDBDIR=/home/user/cryptdb`.

So I just modify the code like this, hope this won't cause another problem:

```
-- assert(package.loadlib(os.getenv("EDBDIR").."/obj/libexecute.so",
assert(package.loadlib("/home/user/cryptdb/obj/libexecute.so",
                   "lua_cryptdb_init"))()
```

Comment: Try `export EDBDIR=/home/user/cryptdb`

Comment: Thanks :) . Fixed the `wrapper.lua` problem. `export` is missing in my `.bashrc` .

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem, start the proxy with:

```
$ /home/user/cryptdb/bins/proxy-bin/bin/mysql-proxy \
--plugins=proxy \
--event-threads=4 \
--max-open-files=1024 \
--proxy-lua-script=$EDBDIR/mysqlproxy/wrapper.lua \
--proxy-address=127.0.0.1:3307 \
--proxy-backend-addresses=127.0.0.1:3306
```

Note the use *127.0.0.1* instead of *localhost*.

For your second problem, add `export EDBDIR=/home/user/cryptdb` to your `.bashrc` as suggested above.