# GET "ERROR 1105 (HY000): (proxy) all backends are down" while run cryptDB on docker contain (ubuntu 12)

Tags: mysql, docker, crypt

I am recently considering to run the MIT's [CryptDB](https://github.com/CryptDB/cryptdb). My system is **Debian 9** which doesn't get some of the necessary Dependency packages (`liblua5.1-0-dev` `libmysqlclient-dev` for example). So I pull an **ubuntu 12** 's docker image and install the **cryptDB** on the container. I am definitely following the readme of the [CryptDB](https://github.com/CryptDB/cryptdb). And I install successfully.

Then I test the `cryptdb` with the command :

```
    /root/cryptdb/bins/proxy-bin/bin/mysql-proxy  
 --plugins=proxy --event-threads=4     
 --max-open-files=1024 
 --proxy-lua-script=$EDBDIR/mysqlproxy/wrapper.lua     
 --proxy-address=127.0.0.1:3307     
 --proxy-backend-addresses=localhost:3306
```

it gets:

```
2018-11-05 14:58:07: (critical) plugin proxy 0.8.4 started
```

And I open another terminal with of the same container and run :

```
mysql -u root -pletmein -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307
```

Unfortunately, it gets :

```
ERROR 1105 (HY000): (proxy) all backends are down.
```

And simultaneously the proxy gets:

```
2018-11-06 02:23:54: (critical) proxy-plugin.c.1865: Cannot connect, all backends are down.
```

I am confused because I am a total beginner to Docker.

PS: here is another programmer who [has the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33332174/cryptdb-cannot-connect-to-proxy-error-1105-hy000-proxy-all-backends-are).

Comment: Did you try to `export EDBDIR=/home/user/cryptdb` to your `.bashrc`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried. It doesn't work.